# vue.js update value when another value changes (data-binding)

Tags: data-binding, vue.js

That's where I change a value:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" id="global-tag1" v-model="liveTag1">
    <label for="global-tag1">label</label>
</div>
```

And I would like to update it everywhere here:
*Attention there are multiple of this pieces on my page. And I cannot do it with custom elements, I've done it and it worked but it takes to long to render the page.*

```
 <div>
     <input name="someValue" value="{{$predefinedValue ?? ''}}" type="text" id="id1">
     <label for="id1">label</label>
 </div>
```

Now how do I achieve this with vue.js. 
Because I cannot simply set

```
value="{{liveTag1}}"
```

Then I do not have a predefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: 'body',

    data: {
        liveTag1: ''
    }
});
```

This will observe the liveTag1 and as soon as the data changes it will update the value of the given Selector.

```
vm.$watch('liveTag1', function(value) {
    $('[id^="someid"]').val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Vue are you using? On current version you cannot do:

```
value="{{liveTag1}}"
```

for input fields, you need to do:

```
v-model="liveTag1"
```

Then if you want to set it to a predefined value, in your Vue instance:

```
Vue({
    data: {
        liveTag1: "something"
    }
})
```

Comment: thanks for your anwser, is not possible to predefine the value in the Vue instance, because it could be up to 1000 elements so I don't wanna write so much data attributes. I solved it with vm.$watch and used normal jquery to change the other values